# Linux Mint 16 - How to launch script from desktop without "Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel, Run" prompt

Tags: linux-mint

Is it possible to remove the  "Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel, Run" prompt that I get each time I double-click to run a script from the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do right-click/Create Launcher on the desktop to create a launcher for your script -- then when you double-click the launcher it will just run without giving you that prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an option within Nemo --> Edit --> Preferences --> Behaviour --> Executable Text Files --> "Run executable text files when they are opened."